# How to keep the check box checked , when navigating to other page of react pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-paginate

We are on 1st page, so I have selected all:

[image: We are on 1st page , so i have selected all]

On second page, selected all:

[image: on2nd page selected all]

Again going back to first page, now check boxes are cleared:

[image: again going back to 1st page, now check boxes are cleared]

Going to the second page again, check boxes are cleared:

[image: again going to 2nd page, check boxes are cleared]

[image]

[image]

I want to ask how to keep save the id's of the check boxes in a state, and whenever I switch back to first page, it automatically searches the element with id and mark check boxes automatically.

And if I uncheck the checkbox, it deletes the id from the state.

I am able to think about the logic, but I'm unable to code it.

Small help, will leads to solve this problem.

While switching to other pages, I am successfully saving the data, by updating the state.

```
// push all the unique objects (combination of previous state of selectedPayments and data from list)
setSelectedPayments((prevState) => {
            var arr = [...prevState, ...list];
            var newState = [
                ...new Map(arr.map((item) => [item.id, item])).values(),
            ];
            return newState;
});
console.log('Selected payments are', selectedPayments);
```

Also, removing the objects, if again the checkbox is unchecked, and updating the state

```
// pull all the objects , which got unChecked
setSelectedPayments((prevState) => {
            var newState = prevState.filter(function (objFromA) {
                return !list.find(function (objFromB) {
                    return objFromA.id === objFromB.id;
                });
            });
            return newState;
});
```

Only facing issue with keeping track of the checked boxes, I have implemented this, this is keeping track of main(parent checkbox).
How to extract the ids saved and check the checkboxes when we navigate from one page to another:

```
let elementId = e.target.id;

if (selectedBoxes.includes(elementId)) {
        const newArray = selectedBoxes.filter((e) => e !== elementId);
        setSelectedBoxes(newArray);
} else {
        setSelectedBoxes((prevState) => {
            return [...prevState, elementId];
        });
}
```

Comment: what table component are you using? Update your question with checkbox on table code.

Comment: Added my table code..

Comment: Store the data you require in a data store such as Mobx/redux, or use the React Context provider.

Comment: So you have a list array in state. You can maintain a `isChecked` property in list item and set `checked={item.isChecked}` in the `<input type="checkbox" />` element.

Comment: @Arjun It's a good idea, I have modified the response json and added isChecked = false, and whenever I check mark the all box, I am setting the isChecked true in selectedPayment state, and comapring both array to set the list array isChecked true, but problem is when ever I navigate from one page to another my response json again came and set the list state to it's defaults false,  at this time my selected Payment state have isChecked true. As check box is getting mark based on isChecked from list. When navigating it is getting reset.

Comment: @Arjun now I am trying to set the checkbox, based on selectedPayment.find((e) => return e.id === item.id) ,,, and it's working, now I can see the checkbox selected when navigating , but again facing new problem, when I am unchecking the objects from selectedPayment array got deleted, but my checkboxes are still marked, untill I switch to another page and come back again

Comment: In the first comment you added, don't put `defaultValue` for `isChecked` as false. instead, search from `selectedPayments` and put `true` or `false`. It'll be working fine even if you change the page and api refetched.

Comment: @Arjun thank bro , for guiding me , a good help always leds to solve the problem , i am attaching my solution.
How i solve this problem.

Better solution always welcomes, or any others fast javascript method to find in O(1) .

Answer (score 0):

First i modified the Res Json , so that it set's a property isSelected = true,
by comparing the element from the selectedPayments
[image]

inAll check handler , i set the selectedPayments like this
[image]

And render using this
[image]

This is how ,i solved this problem.

** Better and improved answers are always welcome, please share your views.

Comment: Please don share picture of code. Instead share as codeblocks either inline or multiline as you need.

Comment: @nur_riyad ok , will keep that in mind ..